# Deploying multiple meteor apps on a single server (multitenancy). Nginx -passenger configuration for 3rd level domain

Tags: meteor, nginx, passenger

I need to deploy more than one bundled meteor apps on the same server, using nginx-passenger. I followed the phusion passenger guide and all works smoothly with one app. No documentation find on how to configure nxinx-passenger (I mean the appX.mydomain.conf in /etc/nginx/sites-availabe) to run more than one app. I need to publish the apps in the form app1.mydomain.com, app2.mydomain.com and so on. Someone can help me to understand how to do? 
Thanks in advance!

Edit: my original config file

```
server { 
    listen 80; 
    server_name app1.mydomain.com; 
# Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is 
    root /path/toApp1/bundle/public; 
# Turn on Passenger 
    passenger_enabled on; 
# Tell Passenger that your app is a Meteor app 
    passenger_app_type node; 
    passenger_startup_file main.js; 
# Tell your app where MongoDB is 
    passenger_env_var MONGO_URL mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp1db; 
# Tell your app what its root URL is 
    passenger_env_var ROOT_URL app1.mydomain.com; 
}
```

Edit: my proposed config file for the second meteor instance

```
server { 
    listen 80; 
    server_name app2.mydomain.com; 
# Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is 
    root /path/toApp2/bundle/public; 
# Turn on Passenger 
    passenger_enabled on; 
# Tell Passenger that your app is a Meteor app 
    passenger_app_type node; 
    passenger_startup_file main.js; 
# Tell your app where MongoDB is 
    passenger_env_var MONGO_URL mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp2db; 
# Tell your app what its root URL is 
    passenger_env_var ROOT_URL app2.mydomain.com; 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your editing and proposals! They are right and all works fine!

Answer (score 0):

You will need a file for each Meteor instance in

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available
```

- similar to the one you have already.

You will need to sym-link these files to

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

The name of the files isn't important except for your convenience, let's say you have domain app1.mydomain.com, so the file is called app1

Save this as

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/app1
```

and issue these commands:

```
cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
ln -s ../sites-available/app1
```

You will just need to sort out which ports each server will run on, and set up the contents of the nginx files (which I assume you did already for the first one)

Comment: Thanks Mikkel, due my faulty english may be I didnt explain well my problem. I know, your comment is the right procedure but my doubt was in what to put inside the app1.conf, and more precisely in the section proxy pass because I didnt know at all behind the scenes how phusion passenger works. I understood that no proxy pass is needed due its module inside nginx accomplish a lot of tasks. So no publishing on different ports the apps, but only is needed to say to nginx the sub-domain to route and the phisical root of the app. I mean:

Comment: Why don't you edit your question to show your original conf file, and then your proposed second conf file. The differences between the two should be minimal, basically just name changes and port changes

Comment: I did but I don't know way it was banned by the moderator

Comment: That's wierd, maybe you don't have enough reputation to do it? Put them in a comment and I can edit it

Comment: the solutions for me was:

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app1.mydomain.com;

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /path/toApp1/bundle/public;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    # Tell Passenger that your app is a Meteor app
    passenger_app_type node;
    passenger_startup_file main.js;

    # Tell your app where MongoDB is
    passenger_env_var MONGO_URL mongodb://localhost:27017/myappdb;
    # Tell your app what its root URL is
    passenger_env_var ROOT_URL http://app1.mydomain.com;
}

Comment: Is this your original file?

Comment: this is the right working file. Just duplicate it, changing the app public directory and the publishing URL. The ports handling is made behind the scene by Passenger (it provides security duties too).